# recursive stack overflow in fibonacci function

Tags: python, recursion, stack, stack-overflow, fibonacci

I'm triying to understand the stack overflow mecanism of a recursive function.
So i used this fibonacci function :

```
def fib(n):
 if n==1 or n==2:
    return 1
 return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)
print (fib(555))
```

when i try this function to calcualte fibo(999) i've got this RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
but when i try to calculate fibo(555) python does not print any runtime error but still work

I know that the default recursive deeptHs in python is 1000 but i don't understant why python does'n print a run time error when i try to find fibo (555)

THK'X FOR ALL

Comment: Please check the recursion. with fib(999) recursion aint called 1000 times but more than that since fib(999) = fib(998) + fib(997)...so it would create a big long hierarchy which is more than 1000.

Comment: @simonzack And you think this counts as a use-case? I don't even think this can be TCO-optimized, at least not completely using the traditional methods.

Comment: @Abhi That's wrong. The *depth* of the call is about 998. What matters are the implied stack frames and the caller's stack frames, which lower the number you can actually use.

Comment: Hi freinds, i try with this example to better undrestand the recursive stack overflow mecanism, i undrestand the case of 999 but not the 555 one, i think python must show a runtime error but he doesn't

Comment: @simonzack [Not going to happen](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com.au/2009/04/final-words-on-tail-calls.html). Tail call optimization is necessary in languages that use recursion as the primary or *only* means of iteration; Python has other idioms for iteration. Your tail-recursive function is inefficient? Don't use (tail) recursion. As Veedrac pointed out, this is not a tail-recursive function, which would require that the return value of the recursive call be returned *immediately*; the value of `fib(n-1)`, though, needs to be saved until `fib(n-2)` returns and the two can be added together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *may* be that the limit is on stack *depth* rather than number of recursive calls, and you may well have used up some of that stack depth before the first call to `fib()`.

With `fib(555)`, you'll only be *adding* `555` stack frames, not `555 + 554`. That's because the two terms of the calculation are done *sequentially.* In other words, `fib(555)` is called and that uses 555 stack frames to do its work, then, and this is important, **unwinds those frames so you're back at the stack level you were at *before* calling `fib(555)`.** *Then* `fib(554)` is called and it uses about the same number of frames.

At no stage are you using more than the extra 555 stack frames. So, graphically, it's *not* doing:

```
_                                      _
 \                                    /
  \           (555 levels)           /
   \__                            __/
      \                          /
       \  (another 554 levels)  /
        \______________________/
```

What it *is* doing is:

```
_       _     _
 \     / \   /  (555 levels down, then
  \   /   \_/    back up, then down
   \_/           554, then back up again)
```

---

In any case, using recursion to calculate Fibonacci numbers is incredibly inefficient since, for `999`, you calculate `fib(998)` *twice,* one as part of the first term `fib(999)` (`998` being done one stack level down) and one as the second term `fib(998)`. Then, for *each* of those two `fib(998)` calls, you calculate `fib(997)` twice. This is a horrendously time-expensive way of doing it, with the runtime rising quadratically (the term may be wrong, and those with more mathematical nous can correct me, but what I mean is that it rises with the square of the number).

Far better to use an iterative solution, such as the following pseudo-code (which, by no mistake, looks a lot like Python, since Python is an ideal pseudo-code language):

```
# Calculate Fibonacci, first term fib(0).

def fib(n):
    if n <= 1: return 1
    grandparent = 1
    parent = 1
    for i in range(n - 1):
        me = parent + grandparent
        grandparent = parent
        parent = me
    return me

for i in range(10):
    print i, fib(i)
```

This is much more efficient than the recursive solution and has no issues with stack overflow. It returns `fib(999)` almost instantly:

```
70330367711422815821835254877
18354977018126983635873274260
49050871545371181969335797422
49494562611733487750449241765
99108818636326545022364710601
20533741212738673391111981393
73125598767690091902245245323
403501
```

as opposed to the full ten minutes I waited for the recursive solution before I got bored and wandered off.

Comment: with this function i try to better understant the use of the recursive stack. I don't undrestant why the call is 555 not 555+554 and i think that the two calles share the same stack,isn't?

Comment: @user3896694, I'll elaborate in the answer.

Comment: But i still have a question in the recursive deepth in python is 1000 why i have runtime error when i try to calculate fibo(995), the numbre of recursive function call is a lettle less than the limit

Comment: @user3896694: I have no idea, sorry, other than that already posited, that you've already used up some stack frames. Or possibly, that the checking within the Python source code is not quite exact. Bottom line is, Python has a limit to stop runaway recursion, whether that happens in reality at 990 or 1000. It's no secret that Guido's not a big fan of recursion which is probably why the limit's there in the first place, enough to allow limited recursion and certainly enough for way beyond normal non-recursive calls, but not going ballistic with it.

Comment: thx for all, just a correction the fibonacci(555) function has more than 554 and 553 because the call of fibo(554) will induice two calls, and each one on them will also induice two other calls. at last we will have a big number or recursive calls but because the calls are done sequentely it will not be over the stack limit